# what is .blade suffix on view file - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I think `.blade` is a reserved key for codeigniter.

I downloaded a website that wrote by codeigniter framework.

view dir:

[image]

controller dir:

[image]

what is `.blade` suffix ? and how this file on controller load this view without any `.blade` suffix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.blade.php` is over come from [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates). And to codeigniter it install by **composer**.

In `config.php` it will be define(or check your controller `__construct()`)

Check these

1. [How to use Blade in CodeIgniter](http://www.codem0nk3y.com/2012/09/how-to-use-blade-in-codeigniter-and-just-about-any-php-unframework-you-can-think-of/)
2. [Laravel-Blade](https://github.com/PhiloNL/Laravel-Blade)

Comment: please look this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452842/unable-to-load-the-requested-file-error-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

`.blade` suffix is not a reserved key for codeigniter. It is the suffix for Blade template engine. This template engine has also been used in Laravel5.1.