# Unable to load the requested file error - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel

In the codeigniter I get this message :

> ```
> Unable to load the requested file: home.php
> ```

controller :

```
cp/
    Login
```

---

views :

```
cp/
    home.blade.php
```

---

```
class Login extends BaseController {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('home','');
    }

}
```

or :

```
class Login extends BaseController {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('cp/home','');
    }

}
```

http://www.vitrinsaz1.ir/Mobile/Vitrinsaz/Pannel/cp/login

Comment: .blade.php is over come from Laravel. And to codeigniter it install by composer.

Answer (score 2):

Hi when loading views remember to make sure that you name it correctly like in your instance you could do the following:

```
    function index()
{
    $this->load->view('home_blade');
}
```

remove the period in the name of the file and replace it with a underscore and then make sure the view file itself is named home_blade.php

Comment: and in your routes file make sure that you specify a route for home like this: $route['home'] = 'login/index';

Comment: .blade.php is over come from Laravel. And to codeigniter it install by composer.

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with Laravel :-p also make sure to include the laravel tag in your question

Answer (score 0):

Hey there I was also encountered by this error and my error was solved by rechecking the parent folder name try replacing cp.

```
 $this->load->view('cp/home');
```

with this

```
 $this->load->view('Cp/home');
```

I think this could be the issue..
My code was working fine on localhost but on server it wasn't loading the view. my error was solved by this.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is correct and you still experiencing that error, change folder permissions :

chmod -R 777 "your folder"

I had a similar problem and that solved it.

Comment: The easy solution of permit all access is very dangerous. At least, indicate it in your answer.